# MySQL: SELCT DISTINCT on two columns into one alias column

Tags: mysql, sql, select, distinct

Let's admit I have this table

```
+---------+---------+
| columnA | columnB |
+---------+---------+
|       1 |       2 |
|    NULL |       3 |
|       5 |       4 |
|       1 |       5 |
|       1 |       6 |
|       2 |    NULL |
|       2 |       3 |
|       6 |       4 |
|       2 |       5 |
+---------+---------+
```

And I want to do something like this (to select the distinct values of two columns into a alias column):

`SELECT DISTINCT (columnA, columnB) AS columnC`

To get this output

```
+---------+
| columnC |
+---------+
|       1 |
|       2 |
|       3 |
|       4 |
|       5 |
|       6 |
+---------+
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could `union` queries on both columns, which (implicitly) returns the distinct values from both columns:

```sql
SELECT columnA AS columnC FROM mytable WHERE columnA IS NOT NULL 
UNION
SELECT columnB AS columnC FROM mytable WHERE columnB IS NOT NULL 
ORDER BY columnC;
```

Comment: thanks, it is working, but it is a bit slow, do I need to index the columns together ?

Comment: An index won't help in this example, because it's scanning all the rows regardless.

Comment: @AnylynHax . . . I'm surprised you accepted this answer because it returns `NULL` as a separate value.  Your question strongly suggests that you want it removed (it is trivial to adjust the answer by the way).

Comment: @GordonLinoff yes the answer is not the perfect one but it was the idea to drop the DISTINCT because UNION makes it "distinct". For some reason I believed union makes what the names says a "union" .. and adds a column to the other. ;-)

Comment: @GordonLinoff I editrd Mureinik Answer to make it exactly what I asked